# How to determine if activex control is enabled or not?

Tags: javascript, activex

I try to do this:

```
</script>
if(activex control is enable)
   document.write('&lt;TD class="br" align="middle" >'); 
else
   dispTD(j);
</script>
```

Is there any function or something like activex.isEnable()? I dont mean is activex installed on browser. I try to mean when the page is loaded, it asks "To help your protect security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage....." and then right click on it. It asks allow blocked content.

I try to do something like:
 if block content is not allowed do dispTD
else document.write('<TD class="br" align="middle" >');

Comment: bear in mind: if you use activeX components, your page will not work in any browser except IE. (you may be okay with that, but it's important to know so I felt it needed to be pointed out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might actually be after is [`window.external.msActiveXFilteringEnabled()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> "Determines whether Microsoft ActiveX Filtering is enabled by the
>   user."

[Here's the MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/05/02/activex-filtering-for-developers.aspx) concerning ActiveX Filtering.

Comment: @merand 1. It does work, 2. Your update makes no sense (and seems to completely change the question)...

Comment: I am using IE8 version

Comment: " To help protect your security , internet explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or Activex controls that could access your computer. click for options.. "

when i rightclick and click allowed blocked content, it runs.but i want to do if (I dont allow) else/*I allow*/ i need to run the code with an if condition...

Comment: @merand This is IE9+ supported - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699456(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: oo thank you very much. that is exactly what I try to do! however my project is on ie8..:/ but thank you